# How does a bootloader know the "expected" CRC value?

Tags: c, bootloader, crc

Let's say we have some firmware, and a bootloader. When we flash both onto the device, during boot, the bootloader would know some "expected" CRC from the binary firmware image. The bootloader would compare the expected vs. actually calculated CRC value from the binary firmware image. If they're equal, it jumps to the firmware application startup address, and if not, it just stays in the bootloader.

What I'm confused is by how the bootloader would know some "expected" CRC value. How does a discrepancy grow between an incorrect CRC value and an expected one? And where does the "expected" one come from?

Comment: Look up "secure boot"

Comment: this value is stored in the image for example at the beginning. The bootloader gets this value, calculates the CRC of the rest of the image, compares the result with that value and if they match jumps to the app

Answer (score 1):

I use two methods.

1. The CRC is stored somewhere in the binary image. Bootloader calculates the CRC of the image and compares with that value. If they match - the image is good and can be executed.
2. Always the same CRC is used and some additional data is appended to the image to match this CRC. It requires a bit more complicated post-build steps.

Comment: The firs you listed is the method I'm working with currently. There's an image header with calculated CRC, and a CRC stored at the very end of the image. The bootloader jumps to the image header and compares it to the value at the CRC address at the end of the image. How could a gulf form between these two values? Aren't the CRC calculated in the image header and the CRC that exists at the very end of the image both derived from the same binary?

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein yes. The issue could be channel issues (eg noise on an I2C line) or a storage issue (failed flash on the device).

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein CRC is to check if the image has not been changed by people or by malfunctioning hardware. Imagine uC controlling a heavy dangerous machine with a damaged FLASH memory.

Comment: In terms of people "changing it"- aren't both CRC values calculated off the same binary?(both the CRC in the header and the the CRC at the end of the image). Or is it possible there could be a case where the binary is modified in the time between the calculation of the CRC in the header and the calculation of the CRC embedded in the image itself?

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein people sometimes want to manipulate the image for their (not always good) reasons. CEC does not have to be in a header or appended to the end of the image. You may use more sophisticated methods of storing it in the image. Then it is almost impossible to find it (or rather too expensive)

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein CRC is very simple, not expensive but a good method. I use CRCs for example in memory pools in my projects used in radioactive environments. Then memory chunk is passed to another function or task it is checked and if it does not match it has to be sent again. You do not want to have wrong readings from the sensors in the reactor :)

Comment: For sensors, it's easier to have an expected CRC, right? Since we expect there to be a certain sensor value, it follows we could generate a more static expected CRC. But let's say we're flashing on new firmware- in this case, how could a mismatch occur between the "expected" CRC and a calculated CRC? Since aren't both going to be based off of the same firmware image?

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein Do you know what is CRC? You comments show that you do not know.

Comment: per my understanding it's a crytopgraphic hash generated from input. So in the case of a firmware CRC it would be the cryptographic of a fully compile and linked firmware binary image

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein So you have an image on your PC (as your compiler, linker and other toolchain utilities are run on your PC) . You calculate the CRC and append it to that file. Then you program the uC with that binary image. During the programming, one byte has been written erratically. The bootloader is calculating the CRC again. Then it reads the saved CRC and compares those two numbers. They do not match. The bootloader knows that image is wrong and it should not pass the execution to it.

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein: a CRC is a NON-cryptographic hash -- it is fairly easily reversable and should not be used if you need security against an adversary.  It is good for protection against random errors (such as from radiation induced bit flips)

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say we have some firmware, and a bootloader. When we flash both onto the device, during boot, the bootloader would know some "expected" CRC from the binary firmware image. The bootloader would compare the expected vs. actually calculated CRC value from the binary firmware image. If they're equal, it jumps to the firmware application startup address, and if not, it just stays in the bootloader.

CRCs are calculated following a well known formula, so the boot loader applies that formula to the full boot record to get what is called the *actual value* (for that, depending on the sofware some programs take of the CRC code comming on the data or not, depending on the CRC algorithm) and it compares with the *expected value* which is the code that comes in the data.

Other programs store in the CRC field a value derived from the calculated CRC that forces the algorithm to return a fixed (depending on the algorithm, but always the same) value (e.g. zero)  This allows simplifying the CRC algorithm that has just to calculate the CRC over the full data, and if it has not been touched (modified) for example, an expected value of zero is expected.

If you are dealing with some established protocol that defines a CRC algorithm to calculate and verify the data in a boot record, you need to look for the documentation on how the CRC is calculated and stored in it.  So your expected value will be described there.

Whith respect to CRCs some algorithms initialize the CRC machine in order to distinguish the stream start from a sequence of zeros by initializing (or prepending to the bitstring ---or the initial polynomial---) a fixed string of ones.  This is easily implemented by initalizing the shift register with ones and start feeding the block contents to the shift register.  Others add a trailing of zeros to xor in that field the calculated CRC (so the total chain of bits should always result in an all zeros expected CRC)  You need to consult the firmware provider to see how the boot record CRC is calculated, as most probably the device will refuse to boot until the CRC is not properly set.